# 'LooseVersion' error when running dissolve() on geodataframe in Geopandas

Tags: attributeerror, geopandas

I'm trying to `.dissolve()` a geodataframe of polygons just like in the example provided in the Geopandas documentation, but I keep getting an error. Specifically:

I run this block of code, [just as it appears in the documentation](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/aggregation_with_dissolve.html):

```
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

world.dissolve(by='continent', aggfunc='sum')
```

The `world` geodataframe loads without any problems, but when I try running the `.dissolve()` method I get this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-58541d0d91bb> in <module>
      1 world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
----> 2 world.dissolve(by='continent', aggfunc='sum')

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-dcmay21\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py in dissolve(self, by, aggfunc, as_index)
    642 
    643         g = self.groupby(by=by, group_keys=False)[self.geometry.name].agg(
--> 644             merge_geometries
    645         )
    646 

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-dcmay21\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in aggregate(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    257 
    258             try:
--> 259                 return self._python_agg_general(func, *args, **kwargs)
    260             except (ValueError, KeyError):
    261                 # TODO: KeyError is raised in _python_agg_general,

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-dcmay21\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _python_agg_general(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
   1171             try:
   1172                 # if this function is invalid for this dtype, we will ignore it.
-> 1173                 result, counts = self.grouper.agg_series(obj, f)
   1174             except TypeError:
   1175                 continue

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-dcmay21\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py in agg_series(self, obj, func)
    697             # In the datetime64tz case it would incorrectly cast to tz-naive
    698             # TODO: can we get a performant workaround for EAs backed by ndarray?
--> 699             return self._aggregate_series_pure_python(obj, func)
    700 
    701         elif obj.index._has_complex_internals:

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-dcmay21\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py in _aggregate_series_pure_python(self, obj, func)
    759 
    760         result = lib.maybe_convert_objects(result, try_float=0)
--> 761         result = maybe_cast_result(result, obj, numeric_only=True)
    762 
    763         return result, counts

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-dcmay21\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in maybe_cast_result(result, obj, numeric_only, how)
    332         # things like counts back to categorical
    333         cls = dtype.construct_array_type()
--> 334         result = maybe_cast_to_extension_array(cls, result, dtype=dtype)
    335 
    336     elif numeric_only and is_numeric_dtype(dtype) or not numeric_only:

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-dcmay21\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in maybe_cast_to_extension_array(cls, obj, dtype)
    391     """
    392     from pandas.core.arrays.string_ import StringArray
--> 393     from pandas.core.arrays.string_arrow import ArrowStringArray
    394 
    395     assert isinstance(cls, type), f"must pass a type: {cls}"

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-dcmay21\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\string_arrow.py in <module>
     33     # file is imported from even if pyarrow is < 1.0.0, before pyarrow.compute
     34     # and its compute functions existed. GH38801
---> 35     if LooseVersion(pa.__version__) >= "1.0.0":
     36         import pyarrow.compute as pc
     37 

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-dcmay21\lib\distutils\version.py in __ge__(self, other)
     68 
     69     def __ge__(self, other):
---> 70         c = self._cmp(other)
     71         if c is NotImplemented:
     72             return c

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-dcmay21\lib\distutils\version.py in _cmp(self, other)
    333             other = LooseVersion(other)
    334 
--> 335         if self.version == other.version:
    336             return 0
    337         if self.version < other.version:

AttributeError: 'LooseVersion' object has no attribute 'version'
```

Any ideas of what's going on? I've tried doing this with other geodataframes as well but no luck.

I have also tried, without successfully fixing the issue:

- Searching for `AttributeError: 'LooseVersion' object has no attribute 'version'`. Results show that it's a common error, but arises in many contexts and makes me wonder if it's something wrong with the inner workings of Geopandas?
- Ensuring I have the most up-to-date version of Geopandas by doing `conda update geopandas`

Comment: Is this in the ESRI ArcGIS Pro version of python by any chance?

Comment: @JKelly, yes, it's an ArcGIS Pro environment. Worth mentioning too that I *can* get geopandas dissolve to work if I set up a completely blank, non-ArcGIS environment. Funny how that works...

Comment: I've been getting this error in the ArcGIS default env (v. 2.8, remote virtual pc) in response to plain old pandas commands, just making regular pandas mistakes that probably should have given some other error message.